# Strange result for an improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{-1/2}}{e^{x}-1} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The improper integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{-1/2}}{e^{x}-1} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$
 is convergent  conditionally.

(Applying ***Dirichlet Test***,$$\frac{x^{-1/2}}{e^{x}-1} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\left(\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}+2}}{e^{x}-1}\right)\left( \cos \frac{1}{x}\right)^{'}$$)

---

I simply input

```
 Integrate[(x^-0.5*Sin[1/x])/(E^x - 1), {x, 0, 1}]
```

*Mathematica* 11 gives the  conflicting result,

```
 Integrate::idiv: Integral of Sin[1/x]/((-1+E^x) x^0.5) does not converge on {0,1}.
```

Why does Mathematica  report that? In order to obtain right conculusion，how 
 to improve the code ?

Comment: Do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your observation has been confirmed by other users.

Comment: FWIW, changing your `x^-0.5` to `1/Sqrt[x]` (`Integrate[]` does not play nice with inexact numbers) shows that `Integrate[]` does not know a closed form for the integral. Nevertheless, after making the substitution $x=1/u$ and using `NIntegrate[]`: `-NIntegrate[ Sin[u]/((E^(1/u) - 1) u^(3/2)), {u, 1, ∞}, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 25]` gives `-0.383169391148902046769798`, which does not seem to be known to the [ISC](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/).